# add tooltip to specific column of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables, tooltip

I have table defined in html as `<table id="tableDynamic"></table>`

And I am updating table dynamically as

```
    $('#tableDynamic').DataTable( {
        columns: [
            { title: data[0] },
            { title: data[1] },
            { title: data[2] },
],

        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row){
                    return '<a>' + row[0]  +'</a>';

                },
                "targets": 0
            },
        ]
    } );
}
```

How can I add tooltip just to specific column `data[2]`

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32240/how-to-implement-a-popup-tooltip-on-a-datatables-cell-that-displays-all-data

Comment: this one worked too  `$("#tableDynamic > thead > tr > th:nth-child(3)").tooltip({title:"tooltipText"});`

Comment: You could also target it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like this (call any other javascript after Datable initialisation is complete):

```
 $('#tableID').DataTable({

    [...]

   fnDrawCallback: function(oSettings, json) {
      //Call JS here
      alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );        
      tooltip('.selector', 'theme');
    }

  });
```

I asked a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156089/how-to-load-extra-javascript-in-datatable-server-side-processing). Look at YouneL answer for more details, and an example to do the same with a call back.